# Wordpress import plugins and theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

I am new to wordpress and exported an xml file from a site that I am working on. I saved the xml file to my computer and then with wordpress I tried to import the xml file so that I can edit the site locally.

About 90% of the file was good- all the images/posts/comments were imported- but the site theme and all of the plugins were not imported. Is there a way to do this? Do I have to manually install the theme and plugins for my local server to work on this site?

Comment: All of the pages were imported too.

Comment: yes, the exporters are db, plugins/themes are files.

Comment: It appears that I would have to migrate the files to my computer with the same name database. However, on the site I don't see anywhere where I can access my phpAdmin to select those files and migrate them to my computer.

Comment: you can download the theme files/ whatever from your file server, phpmyadmin is a db program. But get something like filezila, its much easier to work with, you can open files, edit and save back to the server easily or download entire folders, etc